# Jquery Impromptu

Tags: php, jquery, impromptu

I've been having some trouble adding Jquery Impromptu boxes into a project of mine. The code works fine outside of the project, but when placed inside malfunctions.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function openprompt(){

    var txt = 'Text here';

    function mycallbackform(v,m,f){
        if(v != undefined)
        $.prompt(v +' ' + f.alertName);
    }

    $.prompt(txt,{
        callback: mycallbackform,
        buttons: { Add: 'add', Cancel: 'cancel' }
    });
}
</script>
```

When executed this function will do nothing. If I remove the $.prompt then it will work.
I'm also getting this console message when I execute the function...

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function ( selector, context ) {
        // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
        return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );
    } has no method 'prompt'
```

The code is placed in a PHP file which I think might be causing the problem, but I have tested the code in another PHP file, so its not the PHP alone.

I am planning to use the prompt to display a combo-box which is why I can't use a standard alert.

I'm quite new to these things, am i doing anything obviously wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you extended the jQuery methods when you used this code out side this project? If yes you should include that extension of jquery in this project.

**$.prompt** this means, in your jquery library there is a method name prompt.

If NO, your jQuery library of project is not same with Out side the project where you have tested this code. There must be a method (function) name prompt and you have to include that in your project.

Comment: I've been getting the same problem here, but I didn't understand what do you mean with extend the Jquery methods. Could you please tell me what I need to do?